# Chrome IE-Tab with installed IE9

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, ietab

I'm using the IETab Addon for Chrome to browse to pages where the IE is required. Worked fine untill I installed IE9. After installing it, IE-Tab does not work anymore. I already got the latest version.

How can I run a IE-based window in Chrome with IE9 installed?

Comment: Try a different extension which is compatible with IE9.

Comment: Like which one?

Comment: I don't know; look around. (I'll try and remember to find some once I get home.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible again with the latest version of IETab.